# function call problem

Tags: java, synchronization

i am going to call a function which will retrieve some data value from database. but before that i am sending those data. i am just checking whether those data properly inserted or not with this function call. but inserting data taking some time to insert into the database but my function calling starts before it actually inserts the data into the database. As because of that it is finding that no data is inserted in the database. Can any one tell how do i resolve this issue. How to synchronize this. whether i should get the proper result after the proper insertion into the database. i cant use here runnable interface or thread class. the think that i have to do is to call the data access function after certain time so that data gets enough time to get inserted into the database. please help me out.

Comment: _Subtle remark_: In Java, it is a general habit to call a function `method`. Wherever I hear "function", I default that the language would be `JavaScript`, `C` or a `StoredProcedure`. But perhaps, that's just me.

Comment: I have read twice, but could not understand the question.. You should be more clear..

Comment: Might it be a problem of execute a commit on the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what language you are using, but maybe the function has a parameter which causes it to wait until the query finishes before returning? Something mentioning the word "synchronous?"

Comment: Abhisek you need to post more info I think, like for example how about some code of what you've tried so far this way we can get some idea of what technologies you're trying to employ to make your connection and can get an answer

Answer (score 0):

#### Use the Database Driver

I'm not familiar with JDBC so I'm not sure which tools are/aren't available to you, but it seems like you're doing more work than you need to.

Typically the database driver will inform you whether the query was executed successfully, so you should not need to have your application query the data afterward to verify that the data is there.  Instead, [ask the driver for errors](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlexception.html) to see whether there was a problem with the query.

If you're inserting a large about of data and your database supports it, you may want to [use a transaction](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html) to perform your insert.  This will pass all of the data into the db, attempt the insert, and warn you of any problems.

If there are problems with the transaction, you can roll back, and the database state will be the same as when you started (obviously you will need to handle the errors to save your data).  If there are no problems, you can finish committing the transaction, and rest assured that the database state matches the application state.

#### Alternatives

If for some reason the above methods won't work, you can try to resolve the race condition using an event pattern.  In simple terms, you want to [raise an event](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) when the data is done inserting to alert the validator that it can start reading data.  The validator will listen for that event and trigger when it hears it.

Comment: but the thing is i have to check whether those data properly inserted or not this is my actual project.